# Как выгрузить с веб страницы данные в БД или Excel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, python, ajax

Подскажите может кто сталкивался с выгрузкой данных со страницы в БД.
Утилита какая то может или код, рад буду любой помощи)

Речь идет про эту страницу
[откуда выгрузить данные](https://grls.rosminzdrav.ru/CiPermitionReg.aspx?PermYear=0&OrgDocOut=2&NotInReg=0&All=0&PageSize=100000000&order=date_perm&orderType=desc&pageNum=1)

каждая строка это ссылка еще на одну страницу с данными)
все это в таблица находится)

Comment: у подобных организаций базы данных часто находятся в открытом доступе и доступны для скачивания...это называется ОТКРЫТЫЕ ДАННЫЕ...посмотрите по данной ссылке https://data.gov.ru/opendata/7707778246-grls, то ли это или нет?

Comment: http://portal.egisz.rosminzdrav.ru/files/Инструкция_по_работе_с_данными_ЕСКЛП.pdf

Comment: @МихаилРебров идея про скрипт выгрузки данных, подобие краулера)

Comment: @Kazinitrosdatacom,  к сожалению универсальных парсеров не существует. Т.к. на разных сайтах разные наборы данных, и эти данные лежат в каком-то своём месте на странице и извлекаются с помощью разных селекторов. Возможно когда нибудь для подобных задач можно будет использовать искусственный интелект, но я не уверен что протокол HTTP все еще будет актуален к тому моменту. Пока же приходится писать парсеры самим. И приходится самим извлекать данные и куда-то их складывать. С учетом всего сказанного Вы можете переформулировать свой вопрос, чтобы на него можно было ответить.

Comment: @Kazinitrosdatacom, правильно ли я понимаю, что Вас интересуют не столько конкретные приведенные данные на страницах, сколько способ их извлечения?

Comment: @МихаилРебров да))
есть ли способ например на js извлечь данные с веба в БД)

Comment: @Kazinitrosdatacom, JS выполняется на клиенте.... то есть в браузере...это накладывает определенные ограничения...если только не использовать `node.JS`... https://tproger.ru/translations/web-scraping-node-js/